# To use wp_get_recent_posts to retrieve different database at another server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm accessing to another database on server B from server A. Both also Wordpress server. When I wanna use wp_get_recent_posts and other wp GET functions it doesn't work. Is there anything wrong with my codes?

```
$mydb = new $wpdb( 'username', 'password', 'database', 'stackoverflow.com' );    
$args = array('post_type' => 'product', 
              'post_status' => 'publish', 
              'posts_per_page' => 6, 
              'product_cat' => 'book',);
$recent_posts = $mydb->wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
?>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 marginbottom-20">
    <?php 
        $thumbnail = get_post_meta($recent["ID"], 'community_thumb', true); 
        echo '<center><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" ><img class="img-responsive thumbnail-border community-books-thumb" src="' .$thumbnail. '"></a></center>'; 
    ?>
    <?php
        echo '<p class="paddingtop-10 fontsize-13"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .$recent["post_title"].'</a>';
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/), it looks like `wp_get_recent_posts` is just a helper function. Try remove the object call from your code to just:

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
```

By the way, you should consider using the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class instead.